# What controls this behavior of cd shell built-in?

Tags: linux, bash

I've got two RedHat environments in which a bash script is behaving differently.
It boils down to how bash responds to:

```
mkdir foo && cd foo/..
```

Environment 1 works fine, but Environment 2 reports:

```
-bash: cd: foo/..: No such file or directory
```

What do I need to set in Environment 2 to make this work?

Edit: The actual bash code looks like this and is generated by appassembler-maven-plugin:

```
BASEDIR=`cd "$PRGDIR/.." >/dev/null; pwd`
```

Comment: Do you have permissions in the directory?

Comment: Is  `foo/` being actually created in env2?

Comment: Why are you even `cd`ing down into "foo" and then right back out?

Comment: @GordonDavisson: They're not, they're `cd`ing to `foo`'s parent directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally noticed that one user env had the issue and another user env did not. I diffed the output of 'set' command and saw that the problematic env had CDPATH set.  I unset CDPATH and the problem went away.